# Building ParaView for Visual Studio Express 2010 using CMAKE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, cmake, paraview

I'm using CMake to build ParaView with Visual Studio Express 2010. I'm having a problem with the generated solution. The problem is that one of the entries generated for additional dependencies (the MPI libraries) should be semi colon separated but it is space separated. The result of this is that the linker generates a lot of errors when building the project.

This is the error message:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MPICH2\lib\mpi.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\MPICH2\lib\cxx.lib'.

In the project configuration there's an entry that reads:

> C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\MPICH2\lib\mpi.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\MPICH2\lib\cxx.lib

But there should be two entries separated by a semi-colon:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MPICH2\lib\mpi.lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\MPICH2\lib\cxx.lib

I tried to fix it by correcting the reference to the libraries manually project by project, but it is taking way too long.

I think this could be fixed at the CMake level, or at Visual Studio level (by fixing the additional dependencies entries for the whole solution) but dont really know how to do any of those things. I'm not familiar enough with CMake's architecture to pinpoint what I need to change. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your CMakeLists.txt for a line with `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`.  If this command uses quotation marks inside the brackets, try removing them.  For example, if you have:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MainExe "${lib1} ${lib2}")
```

change it to:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MainExe ${lib1} ${lib2})
```

If this doesn't help, you should probably post the CMakeLists.txt in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the FindMPI module. The quickest way to fix this is to edit the CMakeCache.txt in the root of your build tree. You will need to edit the MPI_LIBRARY and MPI_LIBRARIES entries to use semicolons instead of spaces.